# Linux to Sharepoint upload via Samba?

Tags: file-upload

I have engineers in my company who are Linux-inclined, and they would like to use Linux-based computers to access Sharepoint, via Samba share. On a linux box, if they type the following

```
smbclient -U username@company.com -L Sharepoint1
```

They get this output:

```
Domain=[COMPANY] OS=[Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 6.1]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
42cc4cd1-20c5-4575-b7ea-a96c9726aee4-query-0 Disk      Used by Microsoft Search Server 2010 to copy index files between servers.
ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
Backup          Disk      
C$              Disk      Default share
E$              Disk      Default share
IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
SPBackupTest    Disk      
Domain=[COMPANY] OS=[Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 6.1]
```

But they don't know which 'Sharename' to use. So is it possible to upload files from Linux to Sharepoint? As I understand it, the files uploaded to Sharepoint are not on the Sharepoint server itself but on the SQL Server.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint doesn't use SMB/CIFS.  Instead, sites within SharePoint can be accessed via WebDAV (or HTTP/S or Object Model).  Not even Windows can upload files to SharePoint via SMB :-)

Comment: Hi, On windows, when I go to Explorer \\sharepointsite\sitename, I can actually browse the folders and upload, without the need to map network drive. Is that the same as SMB?

Comment: That is using WebDAV (and it is fairly slow).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I will probably have the user connect to Sharepoint via davfs2 since it is for WebDAV (I think)